# Google Cloud Run allows timeout up to 60 minutes, but other services do not

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-tasks

I have a containerized process running in Cloud Run which does some data transformation in a flask app in Python. It takes about 45 minutes to run. No problem, because Cloud Run allows a timeout of anywhere up to 60 minutes. I'm using a HTTP post request to trigger the process. It is dependent on a different process before it, and it also has dependants of its own. So I've been trying to figure out which GCP service is best for mapping out and executing the workflow.

The problem is that other services don't seem to integrate well with this 60 minute limit. I've tried several different ways to trigger the process:

- Pub/sub - maximum `ackDeadline` for HTTP requests is 10 minutes
- Cloud Tasks - HTTP target tasks have a maximum timeout of 30 minutes
- Cloud Workflows - Steps with a HTTP call have a maximum timeout of 30 minutes
- Eventarc - This just runs on Pub/sub I think? So 10 minutes

From what I can see, a basic requirement for a trigger/requesting service is that it waits until the end of the process to get a response. I find it really weird that all of these services are supposed to integrate well with Cloud Run, but actually we have a certain configuration for Cloud Run where they all fail.

Am I missing something? Is there any built-in GCP service which will call my Run process for me, and wait up to an hour for the response?

Aware I could go down other routes e.g. deploy the container to a VM, but I'm specifically speaking about Cloud Run here.

Comment: Those services are designed for **events** and not long-running jobs. When I create a long-running job, I create an API that has a start job and check job status interface with a method of posting status on job completion. Create asynchronous operations instead of synchronous.

Comment: Agree, I already reported that to the Google Cloud Serverless team more than 1 year ago. No change until now :(

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, thats good food for thought. Still think they should either lower the timeout for Cloud Run or raise the timeout for the other services though. It feels to me like this current way just encourages people to break up synchronous workflows into more parts, increasing complexity.

Comment: For the most part, event-based services are very cheap and sometimes free. When you make them synchronous and long-running, cheap becomes harder. There is a tradeoff in how much customers will pay.